# Javascript 'a' tag incorrect redirection

Tags: javascript

How come the following 'a' tag:

[image]

Redirects to the following wrong link?

[image]

(the correct link is 'https://www.ft.com/content/336e7f52-4189-11e8-93cf-67ac3a6482fd', but the url is redirected to 'file:///home/vincent/wintergreen/bokehIB/%E2%80%9Dhttps://www.ft.com/content/336e7f52-4189-11e8-93cf-67ac3a6482fd%E2%80%9D')

What could be the possible reason for that?

The full code describing the full creation of that page is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086517/html-template-formatter-not-working).

However, my code is python and bokeh package which is a bit niche, and I think that my problem is more of a javascript general thing - hence the reduced simple question.

Comment: It would help if you would post actual code here and not screenshots.

Comment: Your link has some weird double quotes within the double quotes of the href attribute

Comment: as I see there is one extra double quote (" ") cover the url. I mean it should be `<a href="https://...."></a>` , but there seem  `<a href=""https://....""></a>`

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your anchor tag is `<a href=""https://something.com"">Link here </a>` instead of `<a href="https://something.com">Link here </a>`.

Notice that you have double double-quotes (`"`) there.

Answer (score 2):

You have `"` symbols surrounding your url, because it does not begin with a slash, it is considered relative url. try to remove these.